# Yii. Get Users based on role

Tags: yii, rbac

I am using native `CDbAuthManager` to implement RBAC in my webapp. How can I get all the users who has permission to do a role? Suppose I have role named `updateprofile`. I want to get all the users assigned to that role. I searched the documentation and couldnt find a function.

(I know i can iterate through all user models and do a `checkAccess()` in a `foreach` loop, but I prefer a nicer solution )

Comment: If you prefer a nicer solution you should use this extension: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user-management

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I've found to do this is to create an AuthAssignment model that maps to your auth_assignment table.  Then, you can setup relationships, scopes, etc for it and query using it to retrieve all user models.  There isn't anything particularly special about the auth_assignment table (as it is mainly just roles in there).

Answer (score 2):

code like

```
class AuthAssginment extends CActiveRecord{.....
    public function getUsersBaseOnRole($role) {
         return Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                    ->select('userid')
                    ->from($this->tableName())
                    ->where('itemname=:role', array(
                        ':role' => $role,))
                    ->queryAll() ;


}....
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the other replies do not give you the perfect result because roles can be hierarchical and so, you cannot use direct queries or relations. My solution which works well is:

```
// list all users with 'userManagement' role
if($users = Users::model()->findAll()) {
    foreach($users as $id => $user) {
        if(!$user->checkAccess('userManagement')) {
            unset($users[$id]);
        }
    }
    $users = array_values($users); // to reset indices (optional)
}
```